# Paperjs write text

Tags: text, vector, paperjs

I'm trying to understand how Paperjs works and I would like to know if it's possible to write text vectors, if yes how?

I tried Raphael.js before this, and I was almost satisfied with it but it seems that Paperjs is more (cross)browser compliant for some reasons, right?

Some examples would be nice!

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is definitely possible to create texts in paper.js.

```
var awesometext = new paper.PointText();
awesometext.content='awesome';
```

paper is better than raphael because its canvas based. Canvas is better supported on mobiles/tabs and hence the advantage of paperjs. However, since canvas is just a bitmap implementation, zooming will make canvas renderings not so good compared to svg renderings like in raphael.

So, it depends on what your priorities are for your application..

Comment: I needed to render a text in 'high definition'. So i had to use Raphael JS because paper js, as you said, uses canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Paperjs handles text-scaling well, but it uses canvas' native methods to render the characters, so you can't access the vector data once they're drawn.  But I imagine you'd only want vector characters to manipulate their shape, for example, morphing one letter into another, or creating a font editor.

If you just want hi res text then paperjs can do that no problem... or you could just set a bigger font size.

If you want to render text as vectors in paperjs, have a look at https://nodebox.github.io/opentype.js/